# Close Application with FormClosing Event VB.net

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I try to exit my application with form closing event but confirmation message box appears twice.

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
 Handles MyClass.FormClosing

    Dim result As Integer
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to close", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None)
    If (result = DialogResult.No) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Application.Exit()
    End If

End Sub
```

I also tried with this solution:

```
Private Sub FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        'nothing to do here the form is already closing
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
        e.Cancel = True 'cancel the form closing event
        'minimize to tray/hide etc here 
    End Select
End Sub
```

The form is closed but the application i still running.

Comment: Does it show twice if you click yes?

Comment: yes its appear twice

Comment: That code works fine for me so there must be something elsewhere that is causing the problem. Are you sure it's that exact code that is calling twice? Place a breakpoint on `Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)` and run the code. Does it hit it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Closing

    Dim result As Integer
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to close", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None)
    If (result = DialogResult.No) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Application.Exit()
    End If

End Sub
```

Hi,
  I got temporary solution for this issue. The Exit method does not raise the Closed and Closing events, which are obsolete as of .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

@karihalan, I believe, you first need to make sure that the Form1 is actually the startup form of your application. You can confirm this from Project's properties. If so, then you don't even need to call Application.Exit().

Second, try replacing Me.FormClosing with MyBase.FormClosing... Like so:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
```

Also, make sure you are not subscribing to form closing event twice, maybe using Addhandler statement.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Hi Azaz  i tried this but same result is appear twice

Comment: Oh, I think you are subscribing to FormClosing event twice using two Handles statement. One with Form1_FormClosing method and other with FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing. You need to subscribe FormClosing once. In other words, use Handles statement with either Form1_FormClosing or FrmMainPlatform_FormClosing.

Comment: sorry i found two solution in our stack overflow. I just pasted on that solution. Now i had changed my own code with second options. two solution applied in same form

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You can try this to close all forms. I would put it in the main formclosing event.

```
For each f as Form in My.Application.OpenForms
 f.Close()
Next
```

Get rid of that first codeblock. This is what I did and it asked my if I wanted to close only once and it closed when I clicked yes and didn't when I said no.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        'nothing to do here the form is already closing
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
        e.Cancel = True 'cancel the form closing event
        'minimize to tray/hide etc here 
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Roach,  Its closing current form only but still application is running in task manager

Comment: @karihalanudhayasuriyan, can you please check the startup form of you project? What is it set to?

Comment: Does your project contain more than one form?

Comment: yes.main form is one but we have 15 forms its small application

Comment: I would use that second codeblock in the MAIN form in which you are closing the entire application from. It seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Hi Roach, I had checked three forms are open but appication.exit method called formclosing event in same form

Comment: me.close calls formclosing event so mesage box appear repeatly

Comment: then what code do you have in that closing event? I would investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your application has more than one form, whenever you apply a closing event on a startup form it will be repeated as much as the number of forms you have. I have faced the same issue and got it solved by changing the event handles on the other forms Not the startup one just like the example below:

From:

```
Handles Me.Closing
```

To:

```
Handles MyBase.Closing
```